# Reusable functions in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm new to d3 and a pretty average javascript programmer. I've got some code to create a circle, and a function to get the x and y co-ordinates of a point on a circle:

```
var innerCircle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr({
    cx: 100,
    cy: 100,
    r: 50,
    'stroke': 'white',
    'fill': 'transparent',
  });

var pointOnCircle = function(circle, radians){
  var cx = parseInt(circle.attr('cx'));
  var cy = parseInt(circle.attr('cy'));
  var r = parseInt(circle.attr('r'));
  var x = cx + Math.sin(radians) * r;
  var y = cy + Math.cos(radians) * r;
  return {x: x, y: y};
}
```

It works. But I feel like continuing with this approach will make my code a messy grab bag of global functions, and that I should be able to make it object-oriented, so rather than calling:

```
var point = pointOnCircle(circle, Math.PI);
```

I can instead call:

```
var point = circle.pointAt(Math.PI);
```

But this would involve me either attaching a `pointAt` function to a d3 object somehow, or creating my own `Circle` object that has a `pointAt` function, and wraps a d3 object. Is either of these a good idea?

There's other points where I feel like I'd want something similar - kind of like I want to be mapping 'objects' to documents, as opposed to plain old data to documents. Is this a common requirement, or am I missing something conceptually?

What's the best way to approach my `pointOnCircle` issue that I'm having above?

Most of the d3 examples are small, self-contained, and written in one single script. Are there any examples showing how to build something with more reusable functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow d3.js style of functional programming as demonstrated below

```
function innerCircle() {
    var current_attr, current_style, circle_elem;

    var _circle = function (svg) {
        circle_elem = svg.append('circle')
            .attr(current_attr)
            .attr(current_style);

        return circle_elem;
    }

    _circle.pointAt = function (randians) {
        if(! circle_elem)       //If the circle is not drawn yet.
            return {x: -1, y: -1};

      var cx = parseInt(circle_elem.attr('cx'));
      var cy = parseInt(circle_elem.attr('cy'));
      var r = parseInt(circle_elem.attr('r'));
      var x = cx + Math.sin(radians) * r;
      var y = cy + Math.cos(radians) * r;
      return {x: x, y: y};
    }

    _circle.attr = function(attr_val){
        if(! arguments.length)
            return current_attr;

        current_attr = attr_val;
        return _circle;
    }

    _circle.style = function(style_val){
        if(arguments.length == 1)
            return current_style;

        current_style = style_val;
        return _circle;
    }

    return _circle;
}
```

This is a typical example of functional programming. The main object is `_circle` function is obtained by calling `innerCircle`. `_circle` *draws* a circle to an svg according to its set attributes (`current_attr`, `current_style`). To draw a circle to an svg, you can do it d3.js way:

```
var new_circle = innerCircle();
svg.call( new_circle );
```

The `_circle` function has 3 defined methods, `attr`, `style` and `pointAt`. `attr` and `style` are getter/setter functions, if you call them without arguments they will return the current value (getter), and if called with an argument, they will set the current value to it.

```
new_circle.style(); //get the current style

//set attributes
new_circle.attr({
    cx: 100,
    cy: 100,
    r: 50,
    'stroke': 'white',
    'fill': 'transparent',
});
```

You can also call your `pointAt` function similarly.

```
new_circle.pointAt(Math.PI);
```

One last caveat to this programming style is the `return _circle;` statement at the end of all setter functions, which allows chaining. So, your example can be reproduced by:

```
var new_circle = innerCircle()
  .attr({
    cx: 100,
    cy: 100,
    r: 50,    
  })
  .style({
    'stroke': 'white',
    'fill': 'transparent',
  });

svg.call(new_circle);
```

Hope this helps. Let me know of any unclear points.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was after. And then in terms of organising your code, I assume you usually put each outer containing function in a new .js file?

Comment: You can do that. Also, if you are incorporating this in a large project, you should put your functions in separate namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```js
var myProgram = {};
myProgram.circleModule = (function() {
  var innerCircle = d3.select("#svg").append('circle')
    .attr({
      cx: 100,
      cy: 100,
      r: 50,
      'stroke': 'black',
      'fill': 'red',
    });

  var pointOnCircle = function(circle, radians) {
    var cx = parseInt(circle.attr('cx'));
    var cy = parseInt(circle.attr('cy'));
    var r = parseInt(circle.attr('r'));
    var x = cx + Math.sin(radians) * r;
    var y = cy + Math.cos(radians) * r;
    return {
      x: x,
      y: y
    };
  }

  return {
    circle: innerCircle,
    pointOnCircle: pointOnCircle
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="svg" width="200" height="200">

  </svg>
```

Comment: A simpler example relating more specifically to the answer I gave would be awesome.

Comment: (sorry, to the example I gave, not the answer I gave)